# How to filter the category in Django properly?

Tags: django

I have a category function named 'person' in my Django Blog.
In my blog, Each post(article) has 1 ~ multiple categories and when I click 1 of those categories, it shows all the posts under that category.
However, for some categories especially which have only English Alphabets like 'Steve', show the same post multiple times.
I think using **objects.filter** has some problem with filtering it but am not sure what exactly the problem is.
Do you have any solution for this issue?

the below are my codes.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    person = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.person

class Post(models.Model):
        book_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        book_link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        source = models.TextField()
        source_link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        categories = models.ManyToManyField("Category", related_name="posts")
```

views.py

```
def blog_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__person__contains=category).order_by(
    "-created_on"
    )

    context = {"category": category, "posts": posts}
    return render(request, "blog_category.html", context)
```

Comment: Why does a `Category` has a `person` field?

Comment: Because I want to categorize my post by the name of the person related.

Comment: Can you share the `Post` model (or at leat the relevant parts)?

Comment: I have updated the Post model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the same `Post` is returned multiple times, if multiple `Category`s to which it belong match (so contain the query). You can use [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to retrieve each post only once:

```
def blog_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        categories__person__contains=category
    ).order_by('-created_on').distinct()

    context = {'category': category, 'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'blog_category.html', context)
```